# Highcharts datalabels outside of plot area?

Tags: highcharts

On highcharts 3.0.0 (and all prior versions that I used), I was able to position datalabels outside of the plot area.

Specifically I display a label whenever the y-axis value is 0.  And I display it under the chart line, so they end up **under** the x-axis.

To do this, I specified a "y" of 18 in plotOptions > series > dataLabels > y.  This did the job of positioning it where I wanted.

Since upgrading to 3.0.6, this no longer happens.  Instead the "y" value gets "bounced" off of the x-axis.  So a y of 0 sits the label just above the axis.  A y of -18 raises it 18 pixels up, **but so does a y of 18**.

Is this a bug, or intentional behaviour?  Is there anything I can do to fix this problem, other than going back to 3.0.0?

Thanks

Comment: OK, I've answered this myself already.  set crop:false and overflow:none (as per in the API documentation) and it works.  My mistake was in looking for an answer/hint in the changelog, and I couldn't see anything about this in there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per my comment on the question, the solution is to add

```
crop: false,
overflow: 'none'
```

I'll leave this question up in case it helps someone else though.

Comment: Nope. I've got the same issue an this does not work for me: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aZ9VA/22/)

Comment: OP mentioned about x-axis. so not a pie chart. the accepted answer works for me.